# Devexpress change Style (SkinRibbonGalleryBar) in Code

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, devexpress

I need to customize my WinForms-application.
I used the SkinRibbonGalleryBar-item in the designer to change the layout in runtime, for example to "Devexpress Dark Style".
But how can I change that Layout while developing?
So that there is no dialog to choose from but the style is set from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using DevExpress.LookAndFeel;
{
// Access the Default LookAndFeel. 
UserLookAndFeel defaultLF = UserLookAndFeel.Default;
// Ensure that the Office2003 painting scheme will be used. 
defaultLF.UseWindowsXPTheme = false;
defaultLF.Style = LookAndFeelStyle.Office2003;
// Ensure that the Default LookAndFeel will be applied. 
xtraTabControl1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = true;
// Remove the Parent LookAndFeel (if any). 
xtraTabControl1.LookAndFeel.ParentLookAndFeel = null;
}
```

Using look and feel might help Ref: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2412

Comment: thanks @PeterStone for your help. As I am using Devexpress, I can't use the teleriks controls. And I don't have any commands like    Devexpress.Controls or    Devexpress.WinControls. How am I able to solve that with Devexpress?

Comment: that's not working yet. I have the same code as above and added the assemblies, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: how about using the lookandfeel component ?   https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressLookAndFeelUserLookAndFeel_Defaulttopic

Comment: hmm I have a gridControl on my Form, which is actually changing. But the Form itself and any other controls are staying the same.

Comment: This article https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2534 says that I can change the skin in the controls "lookandfell" settings, which I don't have here